# Extending IntegrityError class in Django

Tags: python, django, exception

I'm trying to handle this error
`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value....`

The problem is I don't want to catch all the integrity errors, just the one that has the message "duplicate key value" in it. For example, this is what I'm doing:

```
try:
    activity.save()
except IntegrityError as e:
    # if the error is not a key duplication one then throw again
    if 'duplicate key value' not in e.args[0]:
          raise e
```

My question is if there is a way to extend the `IntegrityError` class so that the child class can check the error message of the `IntegrityError` class?